# How can I check if a string has 9 or more digits?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to detect if a string has 9 or more digits. What's the best way to approach this?

I want to be able to detect a phone number inside a string like this:

`Call me @ (123)123-1234`

What's the best way to pull those numbers regardless of their positioning in the string?

Comment: `re.findall("[0-9]",my_string)` or maybe `sum(letter.isdigit() for letter in my_string)`

Comment: Do you want to check if the string *has* 9 or more digits, or do you want to *extract* all the digits in a string? Question title and body conflict a bit (also, have you tried anything at all yet?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want to check if there are 9 or more digits, not exactly 9 due to some people typing '1' before there area code.

Comment: So you want to *check*, not *extract*, is that right?

Comment: BTW: You actually mean 10 or more digits, I think, because a phone number has 3 + 3 + 4 = 6. But my code below has 9, which is easily changed.

Comment: Is the question (1) "How do check if there are 9 or more digits in a string?" (2) "How can I 'pull' all the digits from a string?" or maybe it is... (3) "_How do I detect a North American phone number?_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it sounds like you just want to *check* whether there are 9 or more digits in the string, you can use the pattern

```
^(\D*\d){9}
```

It starts at the beginning of the string, and repeats a group composed of zero or more non-digit characters, followed by a digit character. Repeat that group 9 times, and you know that the string has at least 9 digits in it.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:\D*\d){9}')
print(pattern.match('Call me @ (123)123-1234')) 
print(pattern.match('Call me @ (123)123-12'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Import the regular expressions library
import re
#set our string variable equal to yours above
string = 'Call me @ (123)123-1234'
#create a list using regular expressions, of all digits in the string
a = re.findall("[0-9]",string)
#examine the list to see if its length is 9 digits or more, and print if so
if len(a) >= 9:
  print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without regex (slower for big strings):

```
print(sum(letter.isdigit() for letter in my_string)>=9)
```

Or part regex:

```
print(len(re.findall("[0-9]",my_string))>=9)
```

Just use python for checking if nine (9) or more digits.

Comment: To answer your "why use regex?" question: Because you may be given an large string with millions of digits. Your solution will count them all and exhaust the whole string, unless your compiler is a genius. The regex with `{9}` will stop after hitting nine digits.

Comment: No problem, cheers. I do agree that regexes are usually overused, so kudos for looking for a non-regex solution. :)